# foreach integers into array

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

since im newbie i have a question

well i have `$nUserID` where store user's id's and is like

```
int(1)
int(2)
int(1)
```

and in `$nAuctionID` i have items id  and they are like

```
int(150022)
int(150022)
int(150031)
```

i need put it in 1 array and make it like

```
array (

[1] => 150022
[2] => 120022,150031

)
```

which user which item id watch

how to do that ?

i though should use foreach , but i cant imagine how will looks

start with

```
 $u[] = $nUserID;
 $i[] = $nAuctionID;`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping them by user ID, the following should result in what you're looking for.

```
$usersWatching = array();

// The following results in:
// array(1 => array(150022, 150023), 2 => array(150022))
// Which should be way more useful.
foreach ($nUserID as $i => $userID)
{
    if (!isset($usersWatching[$userID]))
        $usersWatching[$userID] = array();

    $usersWatching[$userID][] = $nAuctionID[$i];
}

// To get the comma-separated version, do this:
$usersWatching = array_map(function ($value) {
    return implode(',', $value);
}, $usersWatching);
```

Answer (score 1):

this will work :

```
$arr = array();
foreach( $nUserID as $key=>$value)
{
   $arr[$value] =  $nAuctionID[$key] ;
}
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: thats what i got from your question , i hope it will help you

Comment: Array
(
)
reciving empty array

Comment: i tested on my computer, it works fine.are you sure you defined your array correctly?

Comment: yes looks like first need put $value into $arr after this another array to put item_id's

Comment: $u[] = $nUserID;
$u[] = $nAuctionID;

i do like this and reciving

`array(4) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(150022)
  [2]=>
  int(2)
  [3]=>
  int(150022)
}`

Answer (score 0):

Most confusingly worded question `EVA`!

```
$outputArray = array();

for ($i=0; $i< count($nUserID); $i++) {
    $outputArray[$nUserID[$i]] = $nAuctionID[$i];
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($outputArray);
```

That is what I got from your question..